# Determine how long javascript promise took

Tags: javascript, promise

does anyone know of a way I can determine how long each promise took to execute in `Promise.all([...])`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Benchmark Asynchronous Code (Benchmark.js, Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624055/benchmark-asynchronous-code-benchmark-js-node-js)

Comment: I don't think this is a good duplicate. To OP: you can measure each promise separately before passing them to Promise.all.

Comment: measuring each one individually is the only way to do it if you want individual measurements. the duplicate link explains how to do that.

Comment: @Trung Tran here is a simple way of doing this: http://plnkr.co/edit/mS2n71Vte6VPbl7jl6nl?p=preview You can wrap whatever you want.

Comment: perfect, thx!! @dfsq

Comment: would you mind showing an example in node.js? @dfsq

Answer (score 2):

You could make your own Promise.all function.

Below is an example, that returns timings for each promise in an array it returns, the array also contains the results of the promises too, but of course in this demo my `wait` function has nothing to return.

```js
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function myPromiseAll(promises) {
  const starttime = new Date().getTime();
  const timings = [];
  promises.forEach((prom, ix) => {
    prom.then(() => {
      timings[ix] = new Date().getTime() - starttime;
    });
  });
  const result = await Promise.all(promises);
  return {result, timings};
}

async function run() {
  console.log("Starting stuff.");
  const ret = await myPromiseAll([
    wait(1000), wait(2000)]);
  console.log(ret.timings);
  // console.log(ret.result); result of promises
}

run();
```